# Shopify API - Upload Image with PHP

Tags: php, image, api, upload, shopify

I am trying to upload an image to my shopify store with PHP via the API but it is failing.

```
$images = array
        (
            "image"=>array
            (
                "attachment" => $borderedImage,
                "filename" => "rails_logo.jpg"
            )
        );

        # Making an API request can throw an exception
         $products = $shopify('POST /admin/products/#1246990273/images.json', $images);
```

However, instead of getting NULL, I have the following message in my error logs

```
[2015-07-17 23:14:57] local.INFO: <html><body>You are being <a href="https://SHOPNAME.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I thought this was a problem with my access token or api key but I can make other API calls for things like getting a list of products and creating a new product. It's just creating a new image that gives problems.

It's very hard to get any info as not many people seem to be building PHP apps for shopify.

Has anyone else successfully uploaded an image to the api with a PHP app?

Comment: yes, you have to set the complete url of your image, example: `http://yourdomain/assets/rails_logo.jpg`

Comment: I thought that the path is generated by the shopify API as the images are stored on their CDN. Example: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0839/6511/products/ipad2_medium.jpeg?v=1433077136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. This assumes that you're using an access token obtained through [OAuth](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth) (rather than from [a private app](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/creating-a-private-app)) and that you're looking to upload an image from a URL. The access token, shop URL and product ID will need to be swapped for your own. You can [find the Product Image API docs here](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product_image). Hope this helps!

```
<?php
$token = 'youraccesstoken';
$ch = curl_init("https://yourstore.myshopify.com/admin/products/934765124/images.json");
$image = json_encode(array('image'=> array('src' => 'https://cdn.shopify.com/shopify-marketing_assets/static/shopify-default.png')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $image); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Content-Type: application/json",
"X-Shopify-Access-Token: $token"
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: It works. I can now tweak the script to suit my task. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
GLOBAL $token ='put token';
GLOBAL  $store_name = 'put store name';

$value = 'put your product of array';
$valuemetafield = array(
    array(
        'namespace' => 'Product Parent Style',
        'key' => $value['ParentStyle'],
        'value' => 'value',
        'value_type' => 'string'
    )
);
$value['metafields'] = $valuemetafield;

$ch1 = curl_init("https://".$store_name.".myshopify.com/admin/products.json");
$create_product = json_encode(array ('product' => $value));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $create_product); 
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
"Content-Type: application/json",
"X-Shopify-Access-Token: $token"
));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch1);
$savedProductArray = json_decode($result, TRUE);
$savedProduct = $savedProductArray['product'];
```